Why Code coverage is not constant during every run?
We have observed that while running code coverage on some open source code (example: openssl-3.0.0-alpha6, postgresql-9.3.6) results in code coverage difference every time.
What will be the possible cause for this difference in coverage? Is this behavior expected?
gcov version: gcov (GCC) 4.8.5
For example:



It could be because some parts of the code depend on current date or time - or timing in general, or it could be because tests are run in different order and code (inadvertently) relies on static data, which changes subtly depending on that order.

If any code depends on timing - then results will differ.  Similarly, if you use randomization or constrained random tests:  jobs will differ.
You might want to compare the the results, to see what differed.  (lcov can do this)

what's in the *gcov reports

Some GCC versions have a bug that coverage counters aren't added up properly in a multithreaded context. But non-deterministic tests are a far more likely explanation.

@ticktalk: sorry I didn't get you. We have generated .gcda and .gcno file and the coverage report i.e. index.html. The summary of code coverage is already attached in the query.
For code coverage of postgresql-9.3.6, steps mentioned in the below link have been followed (Coverage with Autoconf and Make).
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/regress-coverage.html
